# Passing in the value of an input in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text input type that triggers a javascript function when a numeric value is inserted.

```
<input type="text" value="key" ng-keypress="submit(key)" ng-model="pager.page"/>
```

Controller

```
$scope.submit = function (val) {
        val = parseInt($scope.pager.page, 10) + val;

        if (!$scope.pager.initialized || val > $scope.pager.totalPages) {
            return;
        }

        $scope.pager.page = val;
        $scope.loading = true;
        $http({
            url: 'custom/generate',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $.param({
                filters: $scope.filters,
                page: $scope.pager.page
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.data.data = data.meetings;
            $scope.pager.page = data.pager.page;
            $scope.pager.totalPages = data.pager.totalPages;
            if ($scope.data.data.length > 0){
                $scope.printable = true;
            } else {
                $scope.printable = false;
            }
        }).error(function() {
            $scope.loading = false;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('ErrorOnResponse', {error: 'An unknown error occurred'});
        });
    };
```

It works perfectly fine if i change "key" with a hardcoded value. I want to pass in to the function the value that is inserted in the field. What is the easiest and simplest way of doing it?

Comment: show us your controller..... Assuming you are using angular

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

change the parameter value as following:

```
<input type="text" value="key" ng-keyup="submit(pager.page)" ng-model="pager.page"/>
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: @johndoe do you want the current value from the text box? try multiple char value. Or what is the issue you are getting.

Comment: Yes. Assuming that i write 5 in the input, that is the value that i want to parse.

Comment: @johndoe: your keyup instead of keypress. that will solve your problem.

Comment: ng-keyup will update my value, yes. But i want to also trigger the submit function

Comment: @johndoe: not sure what exactly you want to achieve by this. If i am right then, you want to call submit whenever the value change with updated value.